# Xdebug stopped conntecting to client after a couple of months of perfect work

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, windows-10, xdebug, vscode-debugger

A couple of days ago PHP Debug using Xdebug in my VSCode on Windows 10 stopped working with Xdebug giving the following error:
E: Time-out connecting to client (Waited: 200 ms). :-(
. I've reinstalled different versions of PHP, VSCode and PHP Debug, changing the port, everything failed the same way. I disabled the firewall completely and it still fails the same way.
Here are the relevant contents of my:
php.ini:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = C:\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.7.0RC2-7.3-vc15-nts-x86_64.dll
xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.scream = 1
xdebug.coverage_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\php\profiles"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart  = 1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port = 9345
```

launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9345
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

php.info

```
xdebug
xdebug support  enabled
Version     2.7.0RC2
IDE Key     VSCODE
Supported protocols
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol
Directive   Local Value Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace   Off Off
xdebug.cli_color    0   0
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off
xdebug.collect_includes On  On
xdebug.collect_params   0   0
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
xdebug.collect_vars Off Off
xdebug.coverage_enable  On  On
xdebug.default_enable   On  On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value
xdebug.dump_globals On  On
xdebug.dump_once    On  On
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off
xdebug.extended_info    On  On
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value
xdebug.filename_format  no value    no value
xdebug.force_display_errors Off Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting    0   0
xdebug.gc_stats_enable  Off Off
xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir  C:\Windows\Temp C:\Windows\Temp
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name gcstats.%p  gcstats.%p
xdebug.halt_level   0   0
xdebug.idekey   no value    no value
xdebug.max_nesting_level    256 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames -1  -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump    2   2
xdebug.profiler_aggregate   Off Off
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  On  On
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value    no value    no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  C:\php\profiles C:\php\profiles
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_addr_header   no value    no value
xdebug.remote_autostart On  On
xdebug.remote_connect_back  Off Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time    3600    3600
xdebug.remote_enable    On  On
xdebug.remote_handler   dbgp    dbgp
xdebug.remote_host  127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_log   no value    no value
xdebug.remote_mode  req req
xdebug.remote_port  9345    9345
xdebug.remote_timeout   200 200
xdebug.scream   On  On
xdebug.show_error_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta   Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value   no value    no value
xdebug.trace_format 0   0
xdebug.trace_options    0   0
xdebug.trace_output_dir C:\Windows\Temp C:\Windows\Temp
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3
```

Please help me bring it back to work again :)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the answer is simple, really.
First in VS Code I installed PHP Server extension (ver. 2.4.6) from brapifra and added the following line to the settings.json file:

{
...

"phpserver.phpPath": "Here goes the path to the php.exe file with installed xdebug, e.g.: c:\php\php.exe",

...

}

After doing the above it is important to do the following things in the EXACT order given:

1. Open the file to be debugged in VS CODE and press F5 (start debugging)
2. Press the "PHP Server: Serve Project" icon (it is in the upper right-hand corner of VS Code)

Et voila!

It all comes down to the right order of doing things, cause if you serve your file first and then run the debugger the "time-out connecting to client" error will arise.

Hope some other newbie will save some time after reading this post ;-)